# window.history.back(); Not Working in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a google chrome extension that opens the previous page in a new tab, but with my current code, it just executes and creates a new blank tab. How can I make the history back button work?

Manifest

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,

 "name": "Back",
 "description": "Opens the Previous Page in a New Tab",
 "version": "1.0",
 "background": { 
 "scripts": ["popup.js"] 
 },

 "browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icon.png",
 "default_title": "Back"
 },

 "permissions": [
 "tabs",
 "history"

 ]
}
```

and Popup.js

```
  // Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  var action = window.history.back(1);
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: action });
  });
```

Comment: window.history.back(1) is a function and doesn't return an URL if i'm correct. That would leave your url empty?

Comment: That makes sense, but how would I incorporate it into a usable URL?